# usb mp3 player not showing up using ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, kernel, usb-drive, mp3-player

I have a ONN-W7 mp3 player which windows 7 sees however ubuntu doesn't http://en.onnchina.com/mp3_mp4/product172.html but my ubuntu 16.04 isn't showing it as a device.  I've tried gparted, lsusb, gmtp and Disks.  But my device disconnect right after / and doesn't show up any ideas?

what I saw doing a **dmesg -wH** in a terminal screen when i plugged the device in

```
[Aug20 11:47] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.128563] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=071b, idProduct=3203
[  +0.000003] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: Product: ROCK MP3
[  +0.000001] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: RockChip
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: USBV1.00
[  +0.000410] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0.000117] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 071b pid 3203: 400
[  +0.000032] scsi host12: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[  +0.043454] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0e8b:fdff:fe4e:648e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=145709 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[  +0.000012] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0e8b:fdff:fe4e:648e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=790766 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  +0.010190] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0e8b:fdff:fe4e:648e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=145709 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[  +0.000018] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0e8b:fdff:fe4e:648e DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=790766 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  +1.057267] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.111841] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.215946] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.215977] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.112013] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.216016] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.215941] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.000083] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  +0.203990] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  +0.203881] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 19, error -71
[  +0.112008] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.000121] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  +0.203883] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  +0.203953] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 19, error -71
[  +0.000122] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 19
```

Comment: Looks like the errors happen when it's plugged into a USB 3.0 port every time but only happens 1 and about 7 times when plugged into a usb 2.0 port.  Still investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device doesn't seem to work correctly with usb 3.0 ports but works ok with usb 2.0 ports

Comment: That not might not a problem with the device but with the kernel or ubuntu in general. I have problem with USB3 HDD here.